# Sending Unity Web Request Post returning empty from webhost

Tags: c#, http, unity-game-engine

iv been stuck on this for a long time and I just can't seem to figure out what the problem is. This is working perfectly if im connecting to http://localhost/ but if I try it on my domain and host online then it suddenly doesn't return any information.

This is my httpPost class:

```
public static IEnumerator httpPost(string path, string data, Action<APIHttpRequestModel> callback)
{

    byte[] bodyRaw = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(data);
    var www = new UnityWebRequest(path, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST);

    www.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    www.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    Debug.Log(www.uploadHandler.data); // This still returns the JSON string it's sending

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Something went wrong, and returned error: " + www.error);
        callback(new APIHttpRequestModel(false, 400, www.error));
    } else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text); // This returns empty because server isn't receiving any data
        if (www.responseCode == 200)
        {
            callback(new APIHttpRequestModel(true, www.responseCode, www.downloadHandler.text));
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
        else
        {
            callback(new APIHttpRequestModel(false, www.responseCode, www.downloadHandler.text));
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried debugging and these is what iv found so far:

- If I try to Debug.Log() the www.uploadHandler.data it is populated with data.
- If I output the request data on the server there is no data getting returned
- If I try to connect to the same link, on the web host, through a REST Client, it's returning the proper data
- It definitely is hitting the URL and path specified, but when I try to return the request data, it's just empty.

**TL;DR:** The code is hitting the endpoint, but not returning data (trying to output the data it sent) on a production server, if I do it locally it's working fine. If I try with a REST client to production server it's working fine as well.

**EDIT 1:** I downloaded the latest version of unity, and it seems to be working fine on it, so it's definitely an issue related to unity 2017.3.1f1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176770/discussion-between-michael-guimaraes-and-programmer).

Answer (score 1):

Apperantly this is a bug in some versions of Unity (I'm using version 2017.3.1f1)

The reason this is happening is because unity is sending the following header along with the request: "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" which many server's can't handle.

Adding `www.chunkedTransfer = false;` fixes this and will set it to the header to Content-Length

Comment: I thought the `www.chunkedTransfer` issue has been fixed for long time now. Surprised that's still an issue. Although it works on my side

Comment: Yeah probably something they fixed soon after the version i have atm

Answer (score 0):

the chunkedTransfer solution didn't work for me.
But you can actually do the same thing with the WWW class instead of UnityWebRequest, and for me this was the actual solution.